# bugs or weird behaviors in Scala 2.9

Tags: parsing, scala, type-inference

Notice the following strange behavior (Scala 2.9.1.RC2):

```
scala> val spam = x => log(x)
spam: Double => Double = <function1>

scala> val spam = x => log(x)*log(x)
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
       val spam = x => log(x)*log(x)
                  ^

scala> log(2)*log(2)
res30: Double = 0.4804530139182014
```

How come Scala can infer the type of the first one but not the second?

Another strangeness:

```
scala> def eggs(foo:Int=-1) = foo
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
       def eggs(foo:Int=-1) = foo
                         ^

scala> def eggs(foo:Int= -1) = foo
eggs: (foo: Int)Int
```

What's going on here?  Why does it choke when there isn't a space between = and -?

Comment: Please, do not ask two different things in the same question. The title becomes useless, and it becomes difficult to select "the right answer", as answers may answer one correctly and the other not, and may even not answer both things.

Comment: OK, noted, I'll separate them in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Question 1**. The surprise, to me, is that type inference succeeds at all. Another case that fails to compile is,

```
val spam = x => log(log(x))
```

Generally, the rule is that parameter types (here, `x`) must be made explicit. But apparently this rule doesn't hold for the special case `x => f(x)`, which gets rewritten to `f _`. In other contexts, [this rewriting leads to unspec'ed behavior](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4940).

Note: If there is an expected function type, then the parameter type need not be explicit,

```
val spam: Double => Double = x => log(log(x)) // OK
```

**Question 2**. Without the space, you've encountered the "operator" syntax for types. Here's an example that *does* compile,

```
trait =-[A, B]
trait One
def eggs(foo: Int=-One) = foo
```

This is equivalent to,

```
def eggs(foo: =-[Int, One]) = foo
```

The error message you got (*identifier expected but...*) is saying that the integer literal `1` is not a valid type.